# Stripe::InvalidRequestError (No such token: tok_***)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm creating a new customer by calling a Rails REST api through an Android application acting as a client.

My Rails server has a Charges controller. In that controller (`app/controllers/charges_controller.rb`), I have the following method:

```
def createPaymentInfo
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )
  render :json => customer
end
```

This method is exposed as `https://my-url.com/charges/createPaymentInfo`

Which I've done in the `config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :charges
  resources :users 
  root   'static_pages#home'
  get  '/login', to: 'static_pages#login'
  get  '/register', to: 'users#new'
  get  '/portal', to: 'static_pages#portal'

  match '/charges/createPaymentInfo' => 'charges#createPaymentInfo', via: :post
end
```

I have also set my test secret key and test publishable key environment variables set on my server.

Then in my Android application, I am creating an HTTP POST.

```
stripe = null;
try {
    stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_***");
    stripe.createToken( card, new TokenCallback() {
                public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreditCardActivity.this);
                    String url = "https://my-url/charges/createPaymentInfo?"
                            + "stripeToken=" + token.getId()
                            + "&stripeEmail=" + userManager.getUser().getEmail();

                    Log.d("URL", url);

                    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String responseJSON) {
                                    // your response
                                     Log.d("HTTP-RESPONSE", responseJSON);

                                    try {

                                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseJSON);
                                        String stripeCustId = obj.get("id").toString();
                                        Log.d("STRIPE-RESPONSE", obj.toString());

                                        AuthenticatedUser user = AuthenticatedUserManager.getInstance().getUser();
                                        user.setStripeCustId(stripeCustId);
                                        userManager.setUser(user);

                                        Toast.makeText(CreditCardActivity.this, "Card saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        mDatabase.child("users").child( mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("stripeCustId").setValue(stripeCustId);

                                        startActivity(new Intent(CreditCardActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                                        Log.e("FROM OBJ", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + responseJSON + "\"");
                                    }

                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    // error
                                    Toast.makeText(CreditCardActivity.this,
                                            "Something happened with your payment method.\n" +
                                            "Please make sure you're info is correct",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                    );
                    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                    queue.add(stringRequest);

                }
                public void onError(Exception error) {
                    // Show localized error message
                    Toast.makeText(CreditCardActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However I am getting the following heroku error:

```
2017-02-14T22:37:50.658271+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-14T22:37:50.658187 #4]  INFO -- : [263c291d-a442-4ec1-ab80-c4d9b5a10960] Started POST "/charges/createPaymentInfo?stripeToken=tok_***&stripeEmail=rebeccasheeler@gmail.com" for 24.34.87.34 at 2017-02-14 22:37:50 +0000
2017-02-14T22:37:50.659644+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-14T22:37:50.659593 #4]  INFO -- : [263c291d-a442-4ec1-ab80-c4d9b5a10960] Processing by ChargesController#createPaymentInfo as HTML
2017-02-14T22:37:51.241972+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-14T22:37:51.241865 #4]  INFO -- : [263c291d-a442-4ec1-ab80-c4d9b5a10960] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 582ms
2017-02-14T22:37:51.243029+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-14T22:37:51.242973 #4] FATAL -- : [263c291d-a442-4ec1-ab80-c4d9b5a10960]   
2017-02-14T22:37:51.243067+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-14T22:37:51.243030 #4] FATAL -- : [263c291d-a442-4ec1-ab80-c4d9b5a10960] Stripe::InvalidRequestError (No such token: tok_***):
2017-02-14T22:37:51.243100+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-14T22:37:51.243068 #4] FATAL -- : [263c291d-a442-4ec1-ab80-c4d9b5a10960]   
2017-02-14T22:37:51.243136+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-14T22:37:51.243106 #4] FATAL -- : [263c291d-a442-4ec1-ab80-c4d9b5a10960] app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:9:in `createPaymentInfo'
2017-02-14T22:37:51.242058+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/charges/createPaymentInfo?stripeToken=tok_***&stripeEmail=rebeccasheeler@gmail.com" host=my-url.com request_id=263c291d-a442-4ec1-ab80-c4d9b5a10960 fwd="24.34.87.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=587ms status=500 bytes=1669
```

Why are my customer tokens that I'm creating via Java's `stripe.createToken()` resulting in `Stripe::InvalidRequestError (No such token: tok_***)`?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to make sure that the API key you're using for the Android app and your Rails app are both for the same stripe account, and both in Test mode.  The most likely cause of this is that they're not.